# C++ memory leak float pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-leaks

There's something odd with my code here. I've got this memory leak and found it. It's about 4KB/sec according to task manager. This piece of code gets called 60 times per second.

```
void Shader::setUniform(std::string uniformName, mat4 value){
    float* matValue = value->getM();
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms.find(uniformName)->second, 1, GL_TRUE, matValue);
    free(matValue);
}
```

Being a 4x4 matrix it is a float* containing 16 floats. 60 times per second this leaks 16(tiems)*4(size of float)*60(times/sec)=3840 bytes. It fits with what task manager says. The question is, why there is a memory leak here?

I tried commenting out the 3rd line and the leak isn't there anymore. So it seems that getting the array and deleting it doesn't leak memory, but calling glUniformMatrix4fv() does. Why is it so? I don't have a clue.

---

My matrix class is like this:

```
class mat4{
    public:
    mat4();
    mat4(const mat4& orig);
    virtual ~mat4();
    mat4* initIdentity();
    mat4 operator+(mat4 other);
    mat4 operator+(float value);
    mat4 operator-(mat4 other);
    mat4 operator-(float value);
    mat4 operator*(mat4 other);
    mat4 operator*(float value);
    bool operator==(mat4 other);
    bool operator!=(mat4 other);
    mat4* initTranslation(float x, float y, float z);
    void setM(float* m);
    float* getM() const;
    float get(int row, int col) const;
    void set(float value, int row, int col);
private:
    float* m;
};
```

The implementation is:

```
mat4::mat4(){
    m = (float*)malloc(16*sizeof(float));
}
mat4::mat4(const mat4& orig){
    m = (float*)malloc(16*sizeof(float));
    for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
        m[i] = orig.m[i];
}
mat4::~mat4(){
    free(m);
}
mat4* mat4::initIdentity(){
    m[0]=1;     m[1]=0;     m[2]=0;     m[3]=0;
    m[4]=0;     m[5]=1;     m[6]=0;     m[7]=0;
    m[8]=0;     m[9]=0;     m[10]=1;    m[11]=0;
    m[12]=0;    m[13]=0;    m[14]=0;    m[15]=1;
    return this;
}
mat4* mat4::initTranslation(float x, float y, float z){
    m[0]=1;     m[1]=0;     m[2]=0;     m[3]=x;
    m[4]=0;     m[5]=1;     m[6]=0;     m[7]=y;
    m[8]=0;     m[9]=0;     m[10]=1;    m[11]=z;
    m[12]=0;    m[13]=0;    m[14]=0;    m[15]=1;
    return this;
}
mat4 mat4::operator+(mat4 other){
    mat4 result = mat4();
    for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
        result.m[i] = m[i] + other.m[i];
    return result;
}
mat4 mat4::operator+(float value){
    mat4 result = mat4();
    for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
        result.m[i] = m[i] + value;
    return result;
}
mat4 mat4::operator-(mat4 other){
    mat4 result = mat4();
    for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
        result.m[i] = m[i] - other.m[i];
    return result;
}
mat4 mat4::operator-(float value){
    mat4 result = mat4();
    for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
        result.m[i] = m[i] - value;
    return result;
}
mat4 mat4::operator*(mat4 other){
    mat4 result = mat4();
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
            result.m[i*4+j] = m[4*i+0]*other.m[0*i+j]+
                              m[4*i+1]*other.m[1*i+j]+
                              m[4*i+2]*other.m[2*i+j]+
                              m[4*i+3]*other.m[3*i+j];
    return result;
}
mat4 mat4::operator *(float value){
    mat4 result = mat4();
    for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
        result.m[i] = m[i] * value;
    return result;
}
bool mat4::operator==(mat4 other){
    for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
        if(fabsf(m[i]-other.m[i])<=FLT_EPSILON)
            return false;
    return true;
}
bool mat4::operator!=(mat4 other){
    int numEqual = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<16; i++)
        if(fabsf(m[i]-other.m[i])<=FLT_EPSILON)
            numEqual++;
    if(numEqual == 16)
        return false;
    return true;
}
void mat4::setM(float* m)
{
    free(this->m);
    this->m = m;
}
float* mat4::getM() const{return m;}
float mat4::get(int row, int col) const{return m[row*4+col];}
void mat4::set(float value, int row, int col){m[row*4+col]=value;}
```

The getM() method is this:

```
float* mat4::getM() const{return m;}
```

I tried commenting out everything. It leaks memory only when I pass a float* array (in this case "matValue") to the glUniformMatrix4fv() function as the last parameter.

To be clearer, I found the unifrom to be 0 and tried the call:

```
glUnifromMatrix4fv(0, 1, GL_TRUE, matValue);
```

and still memory leak.
Uncommenting all the line there is no memory leak. Even if the method is like this:

```
void Shader::setUniform(std::string uniformName, mat4 value){
    glUniformMatrix4fv(0, 1, GL_TRUE, value.getM());
}
```

The only way it doesn't leak memory is commenting out the function call:

```
void Shader::setUniform(std::string uniformName, mat4 value){
    //glUniformMatrix4fv(0, 1, GL_TRUE, value.getM());
}
```

But I have to call it, so I'm desperate.

---

Here I used DrMemory since I'm on windows.

[Link to the leak result by DrMemory](http://www.mediafire.com/view/p6oy7t371u1csjo/leak_result.txt)

[Link to the error result by DrMemory](http://www.mediafire.com/view/ao48vtj3wfn11xx/potential_errors.txt)

Comment: We need to know what `getM` does. Maybe it's the call to `unforms.find` that leaks, but how can we know without knowing what any of this code does?

Comment: 3840 bytes per second is not 4MB per second. It's not even 4KB per second. Maybe `uniforms.find` is the culprit?

Comment: @JonatanHedborg You're right, I wrote it wrong, it's 4KB. Sorry.

Comment: @Sputanofono I'd recommend running your code in valgrind, to get (real) memory leaks. The task manager isn't able to show you the memory returned with `free()`.

Comment: It is a lot of things to check here. For example, it's 99% incorrect that you free a matValue, because it should be freed in the mat4 descrutor. Does it?

Comment: I tried commenting out everything. It leaks memory only when I pass a float* array to the glUniformMatrix4fv() function as the last parameter.

Comment: Yes, it's freed when the object is deleted. So I figured out that it's not the pointer not freed and found that is the function that leaks memory. But still don't know how. In fact I deleted both the 2nd and 4th row and it's the same. It's only when I use it into the last parameter of the function.

Comment: @Sputanofono In your mat4 class you need the non-trivial copy constructor and assignment operator too (in addition to destructor). If destructor is buggy, memory can leak even when calling empty function. Are you absolutely sure, that glUniformMatrix4fv causes a leak?

Comment: @Sputanofono Also try to replace uniforms.find to some constant, and check if the leak still alive.

Comment: @Nipheris I did it, as I wrote in the post. The uniform was 0 and I hardcoded it, but still memory leak. And commenting out the function call fades the leak away. So it has to be something with the function.

Comment: What does the copy constructor/destructor look like for your class?

Comment: I added the whole class to be more specific.

Comment: Does your code ever call setM?

Comment: @bashrc No. It doens't. And I see why you said it. Thanks, I fixed it ;-)

Comment: @Sputanofono Your `mat4` class is missing a user-defined assignment operator.  Your code will easily leak if you did `mat4 x; mat4 y; ;...; x = y;`

Comment: @Sputanofono The current implementation of setM is even more wrong as it can lead to two frees on the same pointer. In fact a lot of your code can lead to two free on the same pointer.

Comment: @Sputanofono Why not skip all of the `float* m` stuff and just use `std::vector<float> m;`?  Then a lot of that code is superfluous and no longer needed.

Comment: You can avoid all this gratuitous use of the heap by simply making your matrix hold a 4x4 array of `float`s.  This is literally what every reasonable 4x4 transformation matrix class out there does.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Using `std::vector<float>` still involves unnecessary use of the heap.  A matrix is just a 4x4 array of floats, there's no need to use `std::vector` when the array is fixed size.  `std::vector` is for dynamically resizable arrays.

Comment: @legalize - Then use `std::array`.  Regardless, I would rather have a working program than keep fighting memory leaks, seg faults, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh, I totally agree that `std::vector` is preferable to manually managing raw pointers.  For this case, I'm not sure that `std::array` is going to buy you much, if anything.  4x4 transformation matrices are really a very well solved problem and solutions are abundantly available on the net.

Answer (score 1):

If using OpenGL ES 2.0, according to [the documentation of `glUniformMatrix4fv()`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml), the third parameter must be `GL_FALSE` or else a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error is generated.

[Because OpenGL keeps a set of error flags](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/FAQ#glGetError_.28or_.22How_do_I_check_for_GL_errors.3F.29), and each call to [`glGetError()`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetError.xml) tests and clears one of those flags, the memory leak issue could be the result of Shader::setUniform() generating a new `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error each time that is never cleared.

Comment: Tried it but there is still the leak.

Comment: [this](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glUniform.xhtml) version of the documentation does not call out that *transpose* must be `GL_FALSE`

Comment: @NathanOliver OpenGL and [OpenGL ES 3.0+](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glUniform.xhtml) do not have this restriction.

Comment: Ah.  Oops.  I didn't see the version difference.

Comment: @Sputanofono Try adding a call to glGetError() after the call to glUniformMatrix4fv() to see if there is a different error.  Is `GL_NO_ERROR` returned?

Comment: If I let it run more than once, the first time gives me 1280=>GL_INVALID_ENUM but the rest of the time gives me 0=>GL_NO_ERROR

Comment: @Sputanofono That seems like it was generated by something else before the first call to Shader::setUniform().  Can you post the output of [Valgrind's Memcheck](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.mcrun) running your program.

Comment: @DanielTrebbien Unfortunately I'm on windows. Is there something like Valgrind for windows free?

Comment: @DanielTrebbien I used DrMemory, is it the same? Anyway I linked the result into a text file in my question post.

Comment: @Sputanofono Dr. Memory is a common substitute for Valgrind's Memcheck on Windows, and its output looks similar.  From the log that you posted, I am not seeing anything that would point to a memory leak in Shader::setUniform().  You appear to leak some memory by not freeing memory allocated by the `Game` constructor, and maybe you are not calling `glfwTerminate()`.  Would you also post the "potential_errors" file generated by Dr. Memory that contains the suspected false positives?  One of the suspected false positives might be a true positive memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
void Shader::setUniform(std::string uniformName, mat4 value){
    float* matValue = value->getM();
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms.find(uniformName)->second, 1, GL_TRUE, matValue);
    free(matValue);
}
```

You you pass the `mat4` by value.  This means that you will make a copy of the `mat4` from the caller.  When you make a copy of the `mat4` you allocate new memory for it.  You then get a pointer to that memory with `getM()`.  After you use that you `free()` the memory pointed to by `matValue` and this is where your problem begins.  `free()` will deallocate the memory that `value` created.  Then `value` goes out of scope and the destructor is called.  The destructor then calls `free()` on the pointer you already called `free()` on which is undefined behavior.

Get rid of the call to `free()` in `setUniform()` and since `setUniform()` is a void function you are basiaclly doing nothing since you are only modifing a copy.  I believe you meant to/should pass the `mat4` by reference:

```
void Shader::setUniform(std::string uniformName, mat4& value)
```

Comment: Done, but still there is the leak :-/